# How to make a collage in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

Hello I am working in Photoshop 2017 and trying to create 5 photos into a collage however when I go to crop one of the photos I can't seem to get back to where I started where it shows all 5 pictures again, any suggestions?

Comment: You do not actually want to crop

Comment: Have you even tried googling for collage tutorials in Photoshop?

Comment: Yes however doesn't show how to toggle back-and-forth and most of the videos I seen  step-by-step

Comment: That's because generally, cropping is not used at all when making collages.  Simply select parts of images with the rectangle select tool, and copy and paste will do the job just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If all your photos are in a single document on different layers, you *do not* want to use `Crop`.

`Crop` changes the overall document size to the area you've specified, it does not allow the user to change the pixel data on various layers to be different. Essentially, `Crop` changes your *document* not individual layers. If *each* of your photos is a *different document*, then you can use `Crop` on each *document*.

Of you wish to remove unwanted areas in a *layer*, then use the **Marquee Tool** and draw a rectangle around the area you wish to *keep*. Then choose `Select > Inverse` and then hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. This will remove the pixels *outside* the marquee you drew.

A **better method** is to work in a non-destructive manner and to utilize **Layer Masks** rather than removing image data. Layer Masks merely *hide* portions of layers rather than removing them. This provides the opportunity to return at a later time and *change* what is or is not hidden.

The procedure is similar.

Draw a Marquee selection around the area of the layer you wish to keep. Then click the small `Add Layer Mask` button on the bottom of the **Layers Panel**.

[image]

This will create a layer mask on the highlighted layer making only the are within your selection visible.